# Error Creating Custom Button

Tags: custom-button, case-object, custom-link

Need to create the button for the case related Asset Object.

Description: There is a field Asset(LookUp) on the case object and I want to create the Custom link on the basis of Serial no of the Asset if selected on the Case object.

Code:

```
http://sfapp.jlg.com/SMD/smd.aspx?SerialNumber={!Case.Asset.SerialNumber }&ReqType=MODELINFO
```

Error I am Getting:

> Error: Field Case.Asset.SerialNumber does not exist. Check spelling

Please help me out for this.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, your question sounds like a "do my work for me" request, which don't tend to do very well. This site isn't a coding service, but rather one focused on helping you become a better programmer or admin by helping you overcome specific issues. This question also seems to be asking about how to do something very basic on the Salesforce platform. What have you tried so far? If you're stuck, then https://trailhead.salesforce.com will probably be a better resource for you than this site will.

Comment: You seem to have prepared a URL for your custom link already. Please edit your question to be clear about what support you need from the community.

Comment: Can't we fetch the Asset Filed Serial number on Case object.

Comment: @RaviKumar I have edited your question to reflect your issue. Please follow Derek's comments to learn more about how thing work on SFSE.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you already have the link built and that you are facing an issue while using a field from Asset on Case.

From your comments:

> Can't we fetch the Asset Filed Serial number on Case object

You will just need to use `{!Asset.SerialNumber}` here.

The simplest way to get merge fields is to create a formula field and then insert the desired relationship field to get exactly what you need.